# swiping from pts to pixels in Photoshop CS6 for website design

Tags: typesetting

I am working on my psd in CS6/72dpi.

I went into preferences - rulers/units to change my rulers/type from rulers:inches, type:points to rulers pixels, type pixels. I am finding that when I make the shift the ruler changes from inches to pixels. Yet when I look at the character box, the font measurement goes from points to pixels, but the number stays the same (36 points now says 36 pixels.) If I am going to give my programmer measurements to follow and she prefers them in EM, when I look at a pt/px/em chart converter there is a big difference in size between 36 pixels and 36 points. What to do to give the programmer the right measurement?

Comment: How does that pt/px converter know how large *your* pixels are? Every screen's pixels are of a different size - even more so for screens that can be switched to another resolution *and the screen still stay the same size*!

Answer (score 1):

The em is a relative measurement, meaning the inherited font size.  The em still needs a quantitative value to use as a point of reference. If you simply write `font-size: 1em;` in the CSS, it's telling the browser to display the font at 1x the default size for whichever browser you are using, *typically* (but not always) **16px**.

For most cases, and in my own experience, you would use pixels in design, em in code (though usually specify a default `font-size` in my `<body>` element), and point in print.

Comment: Agree. It is wierd that the programmer uses EM as a starting point.